# Mongodb shell new Date(string)

Tags: mongodb

I am experiencing a very weird issue with MongoDB shell version: 2.4.6. It has to do with creating ISODate objects from strings. See below for a specific example.

Why does this not work.

```
collection.aggregate({$project: {created_at: 1, ts: {$add: new Date('created_at')}}}, {$limit: 1})
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("522ff3b075e90018b2e2dfc4"),
            "created_at" : "Wed Sep 11 04:38:08 +0000 2013",
            "ts" : ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

But this does.

```
collection.aggregate({$project: {created_at: 1, ts: {$add: new Date('Wed Sep 11 04:38:08 +0000 2013')}}}, {$limit: 1})
{
    "result" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("522ff3b075e90018b2e2dfc4"),
            "created_at" : "Wed Sep 11 04:38:08 +0000 2013",
            "ts" : ISODate("2013-09-11T04:38:08Z")
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that you're passing the string 'created_at' to the Date constructor. If you pass a malformed date string to the constructor, you get ISODate("0NaN-NaN-NaNTNaN:NaN:NaNZ") in return.

To properly create a new date you'd have to do so by passing in the contents of 'created_at'. Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to run a date constructor on a string using the aggregation framework at this time. If your collection is small enough, you could do this in the client by iterating over your collection and adding a new date field to each document.

Comment: I understood the syntax to mean that the value associated with the key 'created_at' was being sent to the Date constructor for each record. I will do as you suggested and modify the records in the collection by adding the new specific field (date) I require.

Comment: In the aggregation framework, to use a value for a given key as an argument you add a '$' to the front. However, as of now that is only for arguments to aggregation operators, and cannot be passed into arbitrary code like date constructors.

Some helpful examples here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/

Answer (score 0):

Kindof similar problem:
I had documents in MongoDB with NO dates being set in, and the DB is filling up so ultimately I need to go in and delete items that are older than one year.

I did sortof have date in a crappy human readable string format. which I can grab from **'$ParentMasterItem.Name'**;
Example: *'20211109 VendorName ProductType Pricing Update Workflow'*.

So here's my attempt to pull out the dates (via substring parsing) -- (thankfully I do happen to know that every one of the 100K documents has it set the same way)

```
db.MyCollectionName.aggregate({$project: {
  created_at: 1, 
  ts: {$add: { 
    $dateFromString: { 
      dateString: { 
                /*  0123     (year)
                        45   (month)
                          67 (day)
                 # '20211109 blahblah string'*/
        $concat: [ { $substr: [ "$ParentMasterItem.Name", 0, 4 ]}, "-", 
                   { $substr: [ "$ParentMasterItem.Name", 4, 2 ]}, "-", 
                   { $substr: [ "$ParentMasterItem.Name", 6, 2 ]}, 
                   'T01:00:00Z'] 
      }}}}}}, {$limit: 10})
```

output:

```
{ _id: 8445390, ts: ISODate("2022-12-19T01:00:00.000Z") },
```